# What does the music symbol notification mean

Tags: notification-icons

I'm using my son's hand-me-down Samsung S5.  It runs Android 6.0.1

A few days ago, a music symbol (quaver) appeared on the notification bar.  When I pulled it down, there was just the music symbol with no text next to it.  When I tapped on it, nothing happened and the symbol disappeared.  The next day it appeared again.  I did the same thing and it disappeared again.  This morning it appeared again.

I've done an internet search for notification symbols but I cannot find this music symbol or what it means.

What does this music symbol mean?

**Edit**

The symbol is in the top left corner.  It seems to be related to Android Auto.  It only appears after I've used Android Auto.  What I don't understand is I only ever use the maps application so why is the music symbol appearing?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Try long-pressing the notification, it might show the responsible app for the notification.

Comment: I tried taking a screenshot with the power and volume buttons but the phone reset itself and the icon disappeared.   I'll try it with a PC mirror when it next appears.

Comment: Looks like this is somehow related to Android Auto.  I haven't used the car since the phone was reset and the symbol hasn't appeared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The music symbol is the Samsung Music App.  The reason why it disappeared when I pressed on it is because my data was switched off and there wasn't a wireless signal.

When I got a wireless signal and pressed on it, it initiated some installation.

As for why it suddenly activated itself, my passenger fiddled with the phone controls when I stopped by at a supermarket to get something.